# Is there a way to print the instance of a class from an attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm new to python (and coding in general) and I'm wondering if there is a way to print/find an object if you know the attribute. For example if I've got a class like this:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, nameLast, nameFirst, age, sex):
        self.nameLast = nameLast
        self.nameFirst = nameFirst
        self.age = age
        self.sex = sex
e1 = Employee("Doe", "John", 35, "male")
e2 = Employee("Donevan", "Jane", 32, "female")
e3 = Employee("McHipster", "Ron", 26, "male")
```

And I knew a last name, for example `"Doe"`, I could use it to get and print or store the instance `"e1"`.

```
mystery_function("Doe")
# Output: e1
```

Like I said, I'm new to coding so I may be missing something simple, but I've searching for a solution online for a couple hours, but I haven't had any luck.

EDIT:

So, I feel like I need to explain the rest of what I'm trying to do. Once I've got the instance `e1` I need to use it in the next function.

The idea being, when a user searches a name (e.g. `Doe`) the program needs to locate the object to use it in the next function... something like:

```
def func_next(e): # Where e1 is the output from the previous bit
    print("Hi my name is " + e.nameLast + ", " + e.nameFirst + ", a "
          + str(e.age) + " year old " + e.sex + " working at Company X.")
func_next(e1)
# Hi my name is Doe, John, a 35 year old male working at Company X.
```

I'm hoping this makes sense. From what I understand, `e1` can't be a string, because it would not work in subsequent functions. The code I have laid out is an (admittedly silly) example, but it conveys what I'm trying to do:

Input (string & attribute of an object) --> object reference (e.g. `e1`) --> `function(e)` (Where e is the object reference) --> output

Comment: You must put your objects in some sort of container, e.g.  `list` or a `dict`, and search for them yourself.

Comment: No, because `e1` is not the only thing that could be referencing the instance. Say, a list: `[e1, e2, e3]`, or a dictionary: `{'john': e1, 'jane': e2, 'ron': e3}`. Python variables are all just references to objects and you can have loads of them. Which one would you retrieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could cheat your way into that by creating a dictionary:

```
dct = {e1.nameLast: "e1", e2.nameLast: "e2", e3.nameLast: "e13"}
print(dct["Doe"])
# e1
```

this may not be the best representation of your data as a dictionary though... this may be more suited:

```
dct = {e.nameLast: e for e in (e1, e2, e3)}
employee_doe = dct["Doe"]
print(employee_doe)
```

and in order to have a nice output you should add a `__str__` method to your class.

---

answer to your update:

```
dct = {e.nameLast: e for e in (e1, e2, e3)}
employee_doe = dct["Doe"]
func_next(employee_doe)
```

so this all works as you'd expect it to.

Comment: yup, as mentioned: you'd need to implement `__str__` in your class... e.g. `def __str__(self): return '{0.nameLast} {0.nameFirst}'.format(self)`.

Comment: Thanks, but when I run the code the output I get is: `<__main__.Employee object at 0x000002240EFCB518>` so I recon I'm doing something wrong. I don't think adding `__str__` is going to work for me because I intend to use the output in further functions.... I think it might help if I explained that bit a bit more in my post.

Comment: now it's `Enemy` and not `Employee`?. the second version returns the employee object. you can use that and pass it to other functions.

Comment: whoops sorry. I just copied it over, its `Enemy` in the actual code, I was using `Employee`  here as an example because it'd be easier to explain, but I've fixed it in the comment. I'm updating my question now, so if you can, you could update your answer after. Thanks again.